# Generating a $\sigma$-algebra by a simple function

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

If $X=\sum_{i=1}^4a_i\chi_{A_i}$ is a simple function with the $\chi_{A_i}$'s being the indicator functions. Also the$A_i$'s are disjoint, $a_i$'s are distinct, and $\bigcup_{i=1}^4A_i=\Omega$, the whole space. Need to figure out the exact subsets of the $\sigma$-algebra $u(X)$.

So what I did was to take every possible combination of the disjoint sets $A_i$'s. That is,

$$u(X)=\{\emptyset,\{A_i\},\{A_i,A_j\},\{A_i,A_j,A_k\},\Omega\}$$

Is this correct? What roles (if any) do the $a_i\in\mathbb{R}$ play?

Comment: seems correct to me

Comment: If the $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ and $a_4$ have distinct values, then $u(X)$ will have $16$ elements (obtained by all possible unions of $Ai$'s).  But if the  $a_1$, $a_2$, $a_3$ and $a_4$ don't have distinct values, then $u(X)$ will be smaller. For instance, if $a_1=a_2=a_3 \neq a_4$, then $u(X)=\{\emptyset, A_1\cup A_2\cup A3,  A_4, \Omega\}$. That is $u(X)$ will have only $4$ elements.

Comment: @Ramiro yes the $a_i$'s are distinct. i missed typing that part. thanks